# How to enable/start "Android Debug Bridge" (adb) from a shell?

Tags: adb, android-10

I have a root shell, on an Android device's UART.

There is no screen, only a serial console.

How can I enable/start "Android Debug Bridge", so that I can use adb?

(Neither of the answers on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510232/is-there-any-adb-command-to-enable-developer-options work for me.)

Comment: Thanks, but /system is not a separate filesystem, just part of the RO root, which cannot be remounted RW.

Comment: Have you tried to simply `start adbd`?

Comment: if adbd is running you can mirror display with [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc)

Comment: @Robert I'm talking about `adb` access.  I've only previously got `adb` access using Android Setting's "Developer Mode", hence my confusion.

Comment: i don't know about UART without display. is android system_server even running? *am start -n com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings* + (11x) *input keyevent KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN* and finally if reached the proper row *KEYCODE_SPACE* + *KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT* + *KEYCODE_SPACE* should enable usb-debugging